# Finding an amino acid sequence in a file

Tags: perl

I have a [FASTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) file of a protein sequence. I want to find if the
sequence hxxhcxc is present in the file or not, if yes, then print the
stretch. Here, h=hydrophobic, c=charged, x=any (including remaining) residue/s.
How to do this in Perl?

What I could think of is make 3 arrays—of hydrophobic, charged and all residues.
Compare each array with the file having the FASTA sequence. I can't think of anything beyond this, especially how to maintain the order—that's the main thing. I am a beginner in Perl, so please make the explanation as simple as possible.

PS: Since this is just one sequence, I can simply copy the content to a .txt file, there is no compulsion to use a fasta file (in this case). Hydrophobic and charged are residues(amino acids)- there are 9 hydrophobic and 5 charged residues. It is the name of the amino acid that is in upper case single letter as you mentioned. So what I want to do is find a sequence: hydrophobic, any, any, hydrophobic, charged, any, charged (hxxhcxc) in that order in the protein sequence (.txt file/fasta file). I struggled to re frame my question-hope I'm a little better now.

Comment: Are you dealing with single-entry or multi-entry FASTA files?  According to the Wikipedia page, H is for 'histidine' and C is for either Cysteine or Cytosine (Cysteine in your context, I think).  Yet you are looking for lower-case letters (which are not described at all in the FASTA description); is there some interpretation to do?  When you say 'print the stretch', do you mean 'print the whole entry' or 'print the part of the entry that matches'?  Do you need to print the identification line?  And one of the problems you face is that the pattern match might extend over multiple lines.

Comment: This particular file is just one file containing the sequence of one protein. As I mentioned, h=hydrophobic, c=charged, x=all residues. I want to know if the sequence "hxxhcxc" is present in the protein sequence.

Comment: OK: I can see you're reiterating what you said in the question without addressing more than the first question I asked, which isn't very helpful.  I don't know enough about FASTA files (which is only what I gleaned from Wikipiedia) to know what your data looks like and therefore what you need.  I'm not clear whether your FASTA files really contain lower-case 'h' and 'c'; you say yes but Wiki suggests it can't do that.  I can't help any more — sorry.

Comment: Which amino acids are you calling "hydrophobic"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Fasta files, but regular expressions certainly seem like the way to go here.

**In words**

If you `open` the file for reading, you can process the file line by line, `print`-ing only those lines `if` they match the regular expression you specified.

**In code**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.fasta';           # Open filehandle in read mode

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {              # Loop over line by line

    print $line                           # Print line if it matches pattern
      if $line =~ /h..hc.c/;              # '.' in a regular expression matches
                                          # (almost) anything
}

close $fh;                                # Close filehandle
```

Answer (score 0):

So,  you'll have to decide which are the "hydrophobic" amino acids,  but lets just start with either V(aline),I(soleucine),L(eucine),F,W, or C.

And the charged amino acids are E,D,R or K.    Using this you can define
a regex (you'll see it below)

If you just have the whole sequence in a text file parse it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(IN, "yourfile.txt") || die("couldn't open the file: $!");

$sequence = "";

while(<IN>) {
   chomp();
   $sequence .= $_;
}

if($sequence =~ /[VILFWC]..[VILFWC][EDRK].[EDRK]/) {
  print "Found it!\n";
} else {
  print "Not there\n";
}
```